# How to access MSBuild property from a non-inline Task *without* making it a user-modifiable parameter?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I have an out-of-line task like this:

```
  <UsingTask TaskName="MyTask" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory">
    <ParameterGroup>
      ...
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Code Language="cs" Source="MyTask.cs" />
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>
```

In `MyTask.cs`, I have something like this:

```
public class MyTask : Task
{
  public override bool Execute()
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Inside `Execute()`, I want to access an MSBuild variable `X`.

If the task was inline, I could obviously say `$(X)`, but alas, it's in a separate file.

Now I know I can achieve this by passing `X` as a parameter, but that requires duplicating its value across *all* instantiations of the Task, and allowing the user to customize it, but I don't want those to happen.

How do I just access `X` from inside the Task?

Answer (score 0):

An inline task with a property reference, for example:

```xml
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
<![CDATA[
Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.Normal, "$(X)");
]]>
      </Code>
```

is not accessing the property.

The `UsingTask` element will be evaluated once, the value of the property will be substituted into the content of the `Code` element, the code will be compiled, and the resulting task object will be cached.

If the value of the property is later changed, the task won't 'see' the new value.

Only [global properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2022#global-properties) are available to tasks and only in MSBuild v16 and later. Note that the value of a global property can't be changed within a given project.

The `Task` class that you are deriving from, provides a set of BuildEngine properties. Use the `BuildEngine6` property or use the `BuildEngine` property and cast to an `IBuildEngine6`. The [`IBuildEngine6` Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.framework.ibuildengine6?view=msbuild-17-netcore) provides a [`GetGlobalProperties()` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.framework.ibuildengine6.getglobalproperties?view=msbuild-17-netcore) that returns a dictionary.

To summarize: with the exception of global properties, you can't access properties from within a task. (You also can't set properties.)

Depending on the use case, you could add a new parameter to your task or you could use an environment variable.

In general, when adding a new parameter to an existing task, if the new parameter can be optional with a default set inside the task, that would remove the maintenance of changing existing usages of the task.

Environment variables that exist when the MSBuild process is started are exposed as properties in MSBuild. The environment variables can be directly accessed with [`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Name")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=net-7.0).

If you need a value that is not already an expected environment variable, there is a [`SetEnv` task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/setenv-task?view=vs-2022) which will create or modify an environment variable. `SetEnv` won't cause properties to be created or changed. But you can pass a value by using the `SetEnv` task before your task is called, and then within your task use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` to get the value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But unfortunately I don't see how to access the variables I want. (Example: `VCIDEInstallDir` isn't present in the `GetGlobalProperties()` dictionary.) I'm not sure how making it optional would solve anything either, since I still don't see any no way to set or retrieve it inside the task.

Comment: Except for global properties, you can't access properties from within a task. I edited my answer to be more direct about that.

Comment: `VCIDEInstallDir` is an environment variable. Environment variables are exposed as properties in MSBuild but are still available as environment variables. Your task can call `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VCIDEInstallDir")`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be an environment variable; I get back null when I try to look it up as one. (Are you mixing it up with `VS2022INSTALLDIR` perhaps?) Also, if I have to put `SetEnv` before my task is called, wouldn't that mean I would have to do this every time I call the task, rather than just inside my task definition? If I'm going to duplicate it like this, I might as well just pass this as a parameter - that was the entire thing I was trying to avoid.

Comment: The `VCIDEInstallDir` environment variable is set by running `VsDevCmd.bat` if C++ tooling has been installed. The `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022` shortcut runs this batch file. Locally are you using a dev cmd prompt to run MSBuild?

Comment: Tasks are intended and designed to be general purpose with defined inputs and outputs. I don't think it is a good practice to write a task in a way that it requires a global property or an environment variable. But engineering is about balancing trade-offs.

Comment: I'm just building from Visual Studio. I quite literally do not see anything wrong with what I'm trying to do.

Comment: There is nothing 'wrong' with what you are trying to do, you just can't do it because Tasks can't read properties - except for the special case of the global properties. You may not like that, but that is how it works. Since you can't read any arbitrary property, the next closest is reading any arbitrary environment variable. You may not like that either, but those are the options: use a parameter or use an environment variable. My unsolicited recommendation is to use a parameter.